# Getting EOF on 2nd prompt when using a file as Stdin (Golang)

Tags: go, integration-testing

I am trying to do functional testing of a cli app similar to [this way](http://lucapette.me/writing-integration-tests-for-a-go-cli-application).

As the command asks a few input on command prompt, I am putting them in a file and setting it as os.Stdin.

```
cmd := exec.Command(path.Join(dir, binaryName), "myArg")
tmpfile := setStdin("TheMasterPassword\nSecondAnswer\n12121212\n")
cmd.Stdin = tmpfile
output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
```

The `setStdin` just creates a tmpFile, write the string in file and returns the `*os.File`.

Now, I am expecting `TheMasterPassword` to be first input, and it's working. But for the second input always getting `Critical Error: EOF`.

The function I am using for asking and getting user input this :

```
func Ask(question string, minLen int) string {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    for {
        fmt.Printf("%s: ", question)

        response, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        ExitIfError(err)

        if len(response) >= minLen {
            return strings.TrimSpace(response)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Provide at least %d character.\n", minLen)
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to find out what's going wrong?
Thanks a lot!

Adding `setStdin` as requested

```
func setStdin(userInput string) *os.File {
    tmpfile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "test_stdin_")
    util.ExitIfError(err)

    _, err = tmpfile.Write([]byte(userInput))
    util.ExitIfError(err)
    _, err = tmpfile.Seek(0, 0)
    util.ExitIfError(err)

    return tmpfile
}
```

Comment: Show us how your app reads from its standard input, and–just in case–the `setStdin()` implementation. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: Change the command to `cat` to see if `setStdin` works. If it works, it is your cli app's problem and we would need to see how it cosumes from stdin.

Comment: @leafbebop , I guess, it's working (at least initially) because I am getting first answer correctly.  
@icza , added `setStdin`  
Thanks both of you!

Comment: @Anis I doubt that. Try add a `tmpfile.Sync()` before `Seek`. And, in such a case, I would argue `bytes.Buffer` is far better than a temp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It pretty much looks like in your app your call `Ask()` whenever you want a *single* input line.

Inside `Ask()` you create a [`bufio.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader) to read from `os.Stdin`. Know that `bufio.Reader`–as its name suggests–uses buffered reading, meaning it may read more data from its source than what is returned by its methods ([`Reader.ReadString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) in this case). Which means if you just use it to read one (or some) lines and you throw away the reader, *you will throw away buffered, unread data*.

So next time you call `Ask()` again, attempting to read from `os.Stdin`, you will not continue from where you left off...

To fix this issue, only create a single `bufio.Reader` from `os.Stdin`, store it in a global variable for example, and inside `Ask()`, always use this single reader. So buffered and unread data will not be lost between `Ask()` calls. Of course this solution will not be valid to call from multiple goroutines, but reading from a single `os.Stdin` isn't either.

For example:

```
var reader = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

func Ask(question string, minLen int) string {
    // use the global reader here...
}
```

Also note that using [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) would be easier in your case. But again, `bufio.Scanner` may also read more data from its source than needed, so you have to use a shared `bufio.Scanner` here too. Also note that `Reader.ReadString()` returns you a string containing the delimeter (a line ending with `\n` in your case) which you probably have to trim, while [`Scanner.Text()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Text) (with the default line splitting function) will strip that first before returning the line. That's also a simplification you can take advantage of.

Comment: Perfectly worked! Thank you so much! BTW, using `strings.NewReader` instead of tmpFile and it's a lot handy +1