# Matching strings are not returning true

Tags: go

I'm in the process of setting up a for loop, and I have a specific condition in mind: I want the loop to exit as soon as the user inputs "y." However, I'm encountering an issue where the comparison between the user's input and the string "y" consistently returns false. I've also experimented with the `strings.Trim()` method, but it doesn't seem to resolve this problem.

```
type Cuisine struct{}

func (c Cuisine) getOrders() {
    fmt.Print("Enter Orders [Type \"y\" to exit]:\n")
    for order := ""; strings.Trim(order, "\r\n") != "y"; {
        fmt.Print("\nEnter Item Name: ")
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        order, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Println(order)
    }
}
```

Even after attempting to utilize the `strings.Trim()` method to eliminate any potential newline characters, the issue persists. My initial expectation was that the code would exit the for loop when the user inputs "y." However, this expected behavior is not occurring as anticipated.

Comment: `bufio.NewReader()` returns a reader that buffers data: it may read and buffer more data than what's returned. Do not create mulitple of them, as you may lose data (that will sit in buffers and never returned). Create a single reader, or use the more convenient `bufio.Scanner`. See related: [Getting EOF on 2nd prompt when using a file as Stdin (Golang)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51702102/getting-eof-on-2nd-prompt-when-using-a-file-as-stdin-golang/51702545#51702545)

Answer (score 3):

You're defining the **order** variable outside the loop and then again inside the loop with **order, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')**. This is creating two separate order variables.

Try this:

```
type Cuisine struct{}

func (c Cuisine) getOrders() {
    fmt.Print("Enter Orders [Type \"y\" to exit]:\n")
    for order := ""; strings.Trim(order, "\r\n") != "y"; {
        fmt.Print("\nEnter Item Name: ")
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        order, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')  // <- Use '=' here
        fmt.Println(order)
    }
}
```